# Why the result of this code is the same when the arg is different?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, parameter-passing

*Feel free to make this post as a duplicate if there's already an answer for it because I haven't found the answer.*

Here's the code (first code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int val;
} yay;

yay* New (int val)
{
    yay *Node=(yay*) malloc (sizeof (yay));
    Node->val=val;

    return Node;
}

void chg (yay *lol) {lol->val=9;}

int main ()
{
    yay *boi=New (5);
    printf ("%d\n", boi->val);
    chg (boi);
    printf ("%d\n", boi->val);

    return 0;
}
```

The result of the code above is:

```
5
9
```

And my question is, why it isn't

```
5
5
```

?

I mean, from what I know, to change `val` of `boi` requires `void chg (yay **lol)` and `chg (&boi);` in `main ()`, not `void chg (yay *lol)`. I don't understand much of pointer apparently.

What's the difference with this one (second code)?

```
...
void chg (yay **lol) {(*lol)->val=9;}

int main ()
{
    yay *boi=New (5);
    printf ("%d\n", boi->val);
    chg (&boi);
    printf ("%d\n", boi->val);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boi points to memory location(eg. 0x1233) in heap which has val 5.. u pass the same memory location (0x1233) in chg function and modify the value of same heap location to 9.. thats why u see the boi->val is 9..