# How the parameter of this 2 type of pointer is different?

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameter-passing

In this post ([Why the result of this code is the same when the arg is different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747555/why-the-result-of-this-code-is-the-same-when-the-arg-is-different)), the parameter of `chg` is `yay *lol` and the inside of it is `lol` (notice there's no asterisk in front of it). But why in this code, it shows up an error?

```
void chg (int *lol) {lol=9;}

int main ()
{
    int a=5;
    int *boi=&a;
    printf ("%d\n", *boi);
    chg (boi);
    printf ("%d\n", *boi);

    return 0;
}
```

`[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]`

So, different data types in parameter means it works differently?

Comment: `void chg(int* lol) { lol = 9; }`: `lol` is a pointer, and you're assigning an `int` to a pointer. You probably want this: `void chg(int* lol) { *lol = 9; }`

Comment: Exactly why do you not have an asterisk?

Comment: @Jabberwocky @klutt Sorry if my question is a bit unclear, I do know that the code in this page needs asterisk in front of lol like @Jabberwocky stated, but why in my other post which is (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747555/why-the-result-of-this-code-is-the-same-when-the-arg-is-different) doesn't requires an asterisk? the parameter is `yay *lol` and inside of it, it needs to be `lol->val`, if I make it `` it will give an error `[Error] base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'yay'`?

Comment: You're mixing up pointers, structs and pointers to structs. Read the chapter dealing with pointers in your C text book. Short answer `(*foo).bar` is the same thing as `foo->bar`, but the first form is almost never used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function you should use like this

```
void chg (int *lol) {
    *lol=9;
}
```

Because it is pointer, it keeps an address. With `*` sign, you say that. Go to this address and assign this value.

Also you can use your function like this

```
int main ()
{
    int a=5;
    int *boi=&a;
    printf ("%d\n", *boi);
    chg (&a); //send address of a.
    printf ("%d\n", *boi);

    return 0;
}
```

Like this. It means same thing

Comment: Yes, but why in my other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747555/why-the-result-of-this-code-is-the-same-when-the-arg-is-different), the parameter is `yay *lol` but inside of it is just `lol` instead of `*lol`?

Comment: @LastSecond959 there _is_ an asterisk, but you just don't see it. `lol->val` is shorthand for `(*lol).val`

Comment: because in this example `void chg (yay *lol) {lol->val=9;}` it is same thing to say `void chg (yay *lol) {(*lol).val=9;}` . In structures C has a special operator ->. Otherwise it is a bit uglier